# Is it possible to enforce tagging rules with QAF BDD, if yes how can i do it?

Tags: bdd, qaf

With QAF BDD we can provide the tags as Key and value pair, is it possible to ensure the values that can be provided in the feature file are within the defined set for example:

```
@testType:smoke
```

here the testType should take only values `smoke` or `regression`, and if sombody provides a value other than that, for instance, `functional` or does a spelling mistake it should throw error and should not take that scenario for execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can enforce meta-data by providing [meta-data rules](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/meta-data-rules.html). You can set one or more meta-data rule using `metadata.rules` property which expects list of meta-data rules. Below example shows how you can restrict `testType` to `smoke` or `regression`.

```
 metadata.rules=[{"key":"testType","values"["smoke","regression"],"required":false}]
```

Above rule will fail if `testType` exist and have value other than `smoke` or `regression`. If you want to make `testType` mandatory for each scenario, you can set `required` to `true`.

Comment: Thank you , this is helpful